# vimscript: map x "xx if register not specified

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to know how to judge whether a register is specified or not before press <kbd>x</kbd>. 
 ‌‎​‌‏​‍‏​‎​‏‎​‌‎​‎‍​‏‏‌​‌‎​‌‏​‍‏​‎​‏‎​‌‎​‎‍​‏‏‌​‌‎​‌‏​‍‏​‎​‏‎​‌‎​‎‍

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the register in use is supplied through `v:register` variable. For instance,

```
" force plus register if none was supplied (like "unnamedplus" but for "x" only)
nnoremap <expr>x v:register=='"' ? '"+x' : 'x'
```